# Error launching Ubuntu shell on Windows

Tags: windows-10, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to launch Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 via WSL, I get the error:

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800703fa
Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart LxssManager from Task Manager -> Services.